# Horizontal timeline in pure css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a timeline in pure CSS however I seem to be running into some problems.

When I try to set the timeline div as overflow-x: scroll it still scrolls on the y access.

This is what I've got:

```css
#timeline {
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.event {
  height: 500px;
}

.founded {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

.grant {
  width: 800px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol id="timeline">
  <li class="event founded"></li>
  <li class="event grant"></li>
</ol>
```

I just want each additional entry to follow the previous one and for it all be scroll-able horizontally. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us a demo, it's hard to visualize what the end result is. You'll have to set `overflow-y: hidden` to avoid scrolling, but you likely will want to fix whatever is causing the overflow-y to begin with.

Comment: Thought you might be interested in this. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I literally JUST had to make one of these. This is what I came up with:

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.entry {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #13519C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 4px solid #06182E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.entry img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.entry:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid #06182E;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.entry:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #06182E;
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.entry h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.entry h2 {
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.bar {
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>1990</h1>
    <h2>Entry Title</h2>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" /> Here's the info about this date
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>1995</h1>
    Here's the info about this date
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>2000</h1>
    Here's the info about this date
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>2005</h1>
    Here's the info about this date
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>2010</h1>
    Here's the info about this date
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've only just put in the last line of code into mine before you sent this. Thank you for responding though. Love the design of yours as well by the way.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking to do, complete with the timeline bar and a hollow circle as the anchor.  My only adjustment would be to use an ordered list instead of divs, but it's otherwise perfect.

Comment: How can I display the first box at bottom and second box at the top and so on? Something link this https://prnt.sc/qn3juq

Comment: @NarenVerma - probably something like `.entry:nth-child(2n) { // change position to top }` You could utilize negative left and right margins to squeeze them together at that point if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can refer the below link also

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:500);

body{
  background: #F1F1F1;
}

.container{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.timeline{
  counter-reset: year 2016;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline li{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

ul:nth-child(1){
  color: #4caf50;
}

.timeline li:before{
  counter-increment: year;
  content: counter(year);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #4caf50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timeline li:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -999;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

.timeline li:first-child:after{
  content: none;
}
.timeline li.active{
  color: #555555;
}
.timeline li.active:before{
  background: #4caf50;
  color: #F1F1F1;
}

.timeline li.active + li:after{
  background: #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="http://developerstips.com/">DevelopersTips</a></h1>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li class="active">Bacon</li>
    <li>Rib</li>
    <li>Sausage</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```